# Move caret/cursor to the end position in textarea/input -- Ionic 3, Angular2+

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I use the method below the cursor doesn't move to the end (actually it appears at the beginning) of the textarea... So I can't edit it... How could I solve that?

**HTML**

```
 <button ion-button (click)="addText('hello')">
    Text
  </button>

 <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="model">
 </ion-textarea>
```

**TS**

```
addText(text) {
    this.model = this.model + text;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setFocus` method of the DOM element `ion-textarea` queried by a `ViewChild` :

**HTML**

```
<button ion-button (click)="addText('hello')" #modelTextarea>
  Text
</button>

<ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="model">
</ion-textarea>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('modelTextarea') modelTextarea;
model: string;

addText(text) {
 this.model = this.model + text;
 this.modelTextarea.setFocus();
}
```

Comment: when focusing by "setFocus" the caret will get the position it had last time the input field was focused - i.e not necessarily the end.